# merging by redundant element in lists of lists

Tags: r

I've just run the tclust function from the spider package on some data, which is supposed to assign a series of DNA sequences to clusters by outputting a list of lists of indexes for each cluster. So for example if you have n sequences, you get the integers 1 through n assigned to some set of < n clusters. Here's a mock example with n = 7 sorted into three clusters (test[1], test[2], and test[3] being the clusters):

```
>test <- tclust(CloneSample)
>test
[[1]]
[1] 1, 2, 3, 4

[[2]]
[1] 1, 2, 3

[[3]]
[1] 5, 6, 7
```

The issue is sometimes it assigns the same sequence to different clusters, as in test[1] and test[2] above. I would like to pare down this list of lists so that each integer 1 through n only appears once; if it appears in more than one cluster, I would like those two lists to be merged into unique elements. For the above the output would look like this:

```
>testfixed
[[1]]
[1] 1, 2, 3, 4

[[2]]
[1] 5, 6, 7
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can create a graph with clusters as nodes and edges between nodes whenever there are elements in their intersection. Find connected components and combine them with `Reduce` and `union`. It's very possible that some sort of option for this is available in the package you're using already...